# What is this? "v=spf1 ip4:000.000.000.000 a mx ~all"

Tags: domain-name-system

Where 000.000.000.000 is my servers IP. What is this for IP6?
"v=spf1 ip4:000.000.000.000 a mx ~all"

Answer (score 8):

This is an [SPF](http://www.openspf.org) DNS TXT record saying that the IP in the domain's A record, MX record and the IP 000.000.000.000 are permitted to send email for that domain, and that messages from all other servers should be soft-rejected (`~all` instead of `-all`). For IPv6, it would be, for example, `ip6:ABCD::1234/128` to allow messages from `ABDC::1234`. You can see the [SPF record syntax reference](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) for more information.